# How to get SpeedLimit in HERE reverse geocoding?

Tags: rest, here-api

Calling Here reverse geocoding API, I'm trying to obtain speed limit for specific coordinates. For example, I'm calling:
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=YYY&app_code=YYYY&gen=9&pos=51.759445,19.457216,0&mode=trackPosition&locationattributes=linkInfo&maxresults=1

It was working for a while, but now - with the same coordinates and same app id - there's no SpeedLimit field.

I found something in documentation:

```
Note: All link info attributes are subject to additional licensing. We reserve the right to require authorization on API level for all or individual attributes with future releases. Currently, only the SpeedLimit attribute requires authorization and the attribute is not included in LinkInfo if the client application is not authorized to receive this information.
```

I'm not exactly sure what does it mean and if some took my access and how I can apply for this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using PDE API(Platform Data Extension).

Please see below thread.

[How to retreive speed limit from here maps given a latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412834/how-to-retreive-speed-limit-from-here-maps-given-a-latitude-and-longitude)

Happy Coding!

Comment: I don't exactly get why I should use PDE API, as reverse geocoding also support this functionality. Unfortunately I cannot find SpeedLimit in every call, but why?