# No Speed Limit in response Here Maps Api

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get the speed limit for given latitude and longitude. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55415947/9813285), I recorded the request and response used by [Speed Limit example](https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/link_speed_locator) and tried to follow the same in postman. I just signed up for Here API so I do not have app_code as now they only use apikey for rest and js. I replace the `app_code=xxxx&app_id=xxxx` with `apiKey=xxxx` then it only gives me speed category and doesn't give me SpeedLimit in LinkInfo the response whereas in the example's response it gives the Speed Limit in the response. How can I get the speed limit using the following request?

```
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&apiKey=xxxx&prox=50.395705%2C-104.619669&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxResults=1&additionaldata=SuppressStreetType%2CUnnamed&locationattributes=linkInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Speed limit is no longer supported in R
everse Ceocoder API. please use PDE (Platform Data Extension) API to get speed limit at a particular point.

Request would be like :
https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tiles.json?layers=SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC1,SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC2,SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC3,SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC4,SPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC5,ROAD_GEOM_FC1,ROAD_GEOM_FC2,ROAD_GEOM_FC3,ROAD_GEOM_FC4,ROAD_GEOM_FC5&levels=9,10,11,12,13,9,10,11,12,13&tilexy=536,398,1073,797,2147,1594,4294,3188,8588,6377,536,398,1073,797,2147,1594,4294,3188,8588,6377&app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy

Below are steps to follow:

1. You have to first map your geocordinates(lat,long) to a navigable position(lat,long) for the given coord and the Functional Class(FC1-5) it is located in. This you can achieve by a simple geocoder request
2. You can calculate tilexy values based on the navigable lat,long and pass it to PDE API for querying speed limit layer on that particular FC class.
   Look at https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/link_speed_locator example which covers this exact usecase.

Read more about it in the developer site - https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/quick-start-view-map-data.html

Comment: I copied your sample request with my appid,appcode and it didn't give me a speed limit. Can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/q/55412834/9813285 as at first I thought that the answer solves it but it doesn't. If you can please help me there or add sample requests which will save a lot of my time. Please help me with a sample request for the geocoder request to find a navigatable position nearby, a sample for calculating the. tilexy and a sample pde request for speed limit

Comment: Can you please help?